# How to dynamic add rank on Solr?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 6.1

For some request, I need dynamic add ranking

Solr can do this?

And if I want add ranking from some field value, Is there a way to do it?

Comment: yes, there is a support for some query time ranking, but what did you try so far?

Comment: Can you provide simple example ?

Comment: Exactly what is "dynamic ranking" for you? If you only want to use a value from a field, you can either sort by that field or use it in a function query to get a score.

Comment: @Shubhangi e.g. result [a] rank => 80 , result [b] rank => 70; result [a] field [1] : value => 5 , result [b] field [1] : value => 20, I want to make result [a] rank+5 and result [b] rank+20 ,so the result [b] rank more than the result [a]

Comment: @Mysterion I use config to give the rank like : title^200.0 content^70.0 text^5.0

Comment: @MatsLindh did you mean setup the ranking in config file? like :title^200.0 content^70.0 text^5.0 ?

Comment: @ZivHus What is the logic behind those ranking values? What are the criteria for sorting in that order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function queries to do dynamic ranking. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Additionally, you could try out Solr's `Learning to Rank` module. But you'll have to upgrade to at least Solr 6.4.0.

Comment: Thank you so much, I has study the document, And I found the fieldvalue can do that, But I don't know how to use it in config file?

Comment: did you have a sample?

Comment: Hi @drjz  
did you have a sample?